# Importing special/custom csv files to QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, extents

I'm trying to import a csv file. Most similar cases are trivial but the csv file contains only the data (sunshine hours) and a header specifying the coordinate of the first cell, the number of columns and rows and the cell size. Is there any way to automate the import in QGIS or do I have to reformat the file and calculate each position?

Snippet:

```
NCOLS  280
NROWS  220
XLLCORNER 4452000
YLLCORNER 5324000
CELLSIZE 100
NODATA_VALUE  -99.9


  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.6  29.6  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.9  29.9  29.9  30.0  30.0  30.0  30.1  30.2  31.1  33.8  33.8  32.1  32.2  34.5  35.2  34.0  27.2  26.1  24.7  25.4  29.4  29.0  29.3  26.2  27.2  30.0  30.1  30.2  30.4  30.4  30.4  30.5  31.0  31.1  32.1  33.9  35.2  36.0  36.2  35.5  35.8  36.3  36.6  36.6  36.6  36.8  36.7  36.5  36.3  35.1  34.5  32.5  31.7  31.5  31.5  31.4  31.3  31.2  31.2  31.1  31.1  31.1  31.0  31.0  30.9  31.0  30.9  30.9  30.9  30.9  30.9  30.8  30.7  30.7  30.6  30.6  30.6  30.6  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.3  30.2  30.3  30.3  30.3  30.3  29.9  30.0  30.8  30.7  30.7  30.7  30.7  30.7  30.7  30.6  30.6  30.6  30.5  30.0  30.0  29.9  26.7  28.7  28.5  26.7  26.7  27.2  30.1  30.3  30.4  30.4  30.4  30.8  31.0  31.0  31.0  31.2  31.2  31.7  31.8  31.9  32.6  35.0  35.9  34.8  32.0  31.5  30.7  30.4  30.2  30.1  29.6  28.9  28.6  28.6  28.5  28.5  28.6  28.5  28.5  28.5  28.5  28.5  28.5  28.5  28.5  28.6  28.1  23.5  21.8  21.0  20.6  20.4  20.4  20.4  20.4  20.6  21.1  21.7  23.3  26.2  30.5  38.8  39.5  40.5  40.6  40.0  39.9  40.2  40.8  40.2  40.4  40.9  41.0  41.0  41.0  40.4  40.2  40.1  39.9  39.7  39.4  37.8  33.7  32.4  33.0  34.7  35.3  35.5  34.8  34.4  32.8  32.5  32.4  33.0  36.0  36.6  36.7  36.8  36.9  37.0  37.1  36.6  35.1  32.9  32.4  31.8  31.1  30.5  30.3  30.2  30.2  29.9  29.8  29.7  29.3  29.3  25.1  21.1  20.1  20.1  20.9  21.0  20.4  21.0  20.5  20.5  23.3  30.3  30.7  32.1  34.5  35.3  35.6  34.9  33.9  31.9  30.9  30.8  30.7  30.7  30.7  30.7  30.7  30.7  30.7  30.6  30.5  29.6  29.5  29.5  29.4  29.4  29.4  29.5  29.4  29.4
```

Comment: Might be useful to post an example of the csv.

Comment: sounds more like as ASCII raster

Comment: some python would be helpful, please post an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Llaves suggests that is an ASCII Grid file not a CSV file, so you need to use the raster import tool not the vector one.

[image]

Comment: Or drag and drop to the QGIS window, than you don't have to bother which data type it is (does not work of course if you want to create geometries of a CSV, but for an ASCII grid, it should work).